# Does registerTempTable cause the table to get cached?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a sql statement query which is doing a group by on many fields. The tables that it uses is also big (4TB in size). I'm registering the table as a temp table. However I don't know whether the table gets cached or not when I'm registering it as a temp table? I also don't know whether it is more performant if I convert my query into Scala function (e.g. df.groupby().aggr()...) rather than having it as a sql statement. Any help on that?

Answer (score 6):

SQL is most likely going to be the fastest by far [Databricks blog](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html)

Did you try to partition/repartition your dataframe as well to see whether it improves the performance?

Regarding registerTempTable: it only registers the table within a spark context. You can check with the UI.

```
val test = List((1,2,3),(4,5,6)).toDF("bla","blb","blc")
test.createOrReplaceTempView("test")
test.show()
```

Storage is blank

vs

```
val test = List((1,2,3),(4,5,6)).toDF("bla","blb","blc")
test.createOrReplaceTempView("test").cache()
test.show()
```

[image]

by the way registerTempTable is deprecated in Spark 2.0 and has been replaced by

> createOrReplaceTempView

Comment: When I try to run `df.createOrReplaceTempView("test").cache()` I get an exception that `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cache'`.

Answer (score 4):

> I have a sql statement query which is doing a group by on many fields. The tables that it uses is also big (4TB in size). I'm registering the table as a temp table. However I don't know whether the table gets cached or not when I'm registering it as a temp table?

The registerTempTabele  or createOrReplaceTempView doesn't cache the data into memory or disc itself unless you use cache() function.

> I also don't know whether it is more performant if I convert my query into Scala function (e.g. df.groupby().aggr()...) rather than having it as a sql statement. Any help on that?

Keep in mind the sql terms in sql query ultimately call the function inside. so whether you use sql query terms or functions available in code it doesn't matter. that is same thing.